# drop the non exist row value from dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have dataset A and B

```
A['colA'] = [1,2,3,4,5]
B['colA']= [1,2,3]
```

I want to drop all A['colA']'s 4,5 because it does not exist in dataframe B

Comment: `A[A['colA'].isin(B['colA'])]`?

Comment: how many columns do you have in each dataframe?